What is the behavior of a magnet floating in a superfluid that rotates indefinitely?
A superfluid has zero viscosity. If a vortex is created, it can rotate indefinitely without any loss of energy. There are objects less dense than a superfluid that can float on its surface, where a magnet can be placed. If a vortex is created in this liquid, the magnet will move indefinitely.
If a bulb is placed in a closed circuit next to a moving magnet, the bulb will light up through electromagnetic induction.
Here, the purpose of these questions is to understand why the bulb does not always light up through electromagnetic induction, even if the magnet moves indefinitely due to the vortex properties of a superfluid...
What is the behavior of a magnet floating in a superfluid that rotates indefinitely?
Why doesn’t the bulb light up indefinitely, even if the magnet moves indefinitely without any loss of energy?

If a bulb is placed in a closed circuit next to a moving magnet, the bulb will light up through electromagnetic induction.

How was the vortex in the fluid created in the first place?   Just because it is a superfluid does not mean that you can't have forces that influence the fluid, either spinning it up or down.
The magnetic field will create a torque on the magnet, slowing it down.   At that point you have one of two scenarios:

The superfluid moves past the stationary magnet indefinitely.  Energy remains in the fluid's rotation, but the LED is off.
The drag from the magnet stops the rotation of the superfluid.   The LED is off.

